# Javascript Timezone get Location similar to PHP DateTimeZone::getLocation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, timezone, location

Does anyone know of a library, function or API that functions the same way as the PHP DateTimeZone::getLocation - http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getlocation.php but for Javascript (or NodeJS NPM).

Please note not looking for code just to point me in the right direction. Tried looking for something similar could find anything.

**For example -**

I want to take either UTC offset or timezone:

```
utc_offset: -25200,
time_zone: 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)',
```

Then return the location / geolocation based on that:

```
country_code: CZ
latitude: 50.08333
longitude: 14.43333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a small API based off the PHP DateTimeZone::getLocation function as I was pressed for time. I might make this a Public API at a later stage.

Here's the gitHub to download too: 
https://github.com/sputn1k/timezoneGetLocationAPI/

```
<?php

//usage: /?timezone=Europe/Prague
//output(JSON): {"country_code":"CZ","latitude":50.08333,"longitude":14.43333,"comments":""}

if(isset($_GET['timezone'])) {

    $timezone = $_GET['timezone'];

    try {

        $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
        output(timezone_location_get($timezone));

    } catch(Exception $error) {
        output(array('error' => 'bad timezone')); //or add $error for full message 
    }
}

function output($data){
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JodaAPI.
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html
Hope it helpful ^^

Comment: Thanks allot @thanhnd25 i will take a look and mark as answer if i find use this, cheers

Comment: Just had a quick look looks like JodaAPI is a "Java" API not "Javascript" ?

Comment: thanks i will take a look later, i just made a small Javascript API based off the PHP DateTimeZone::getLocation.